# How did the Crusades affect the King's power?

Tags: crusades

How did the Crusades affect the King's power/authority, during and after the Crusades?

Comment: I think this is more of a History question than a Christianity question. Even then, there may be so many ways that the Crusades can affect the King's power.

Comment: I think this is on topic and an interesting question that could be addressed with a high-level overview.

Comment: Which king are you referring to? There were dozens of kings affected by the Crusades..

Comment: Is this already sufficiently answered, implicitly, by the section on kings in [my answer to your other question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/19092/545)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about political history, not Christianity.


Answer (score 2):

They helped to break down feudalism by increasing the authority of kings.

- Some nobles died in battle without leaving an heir. Their lands passed to the king.
- Some nobles sold their land in an effort to raise money to pay the special tax levied by the king to offset the cost of the crusades.
- Some nobles gave their serfs a chance to buy their freedom in an effort to raise money they needed to buy armor and weapons
- Some young men who could buy their way out of feudal obligation joined the crusades. Many died. That reduced the work force. If a farm failed, it passed to the king.

Comment: It's worth commenting that forfeiture to the Crown was (is!) a feature of **English** law.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  This next has nothing to do with the quality of your answer, it's just standard to help new visitors avoid misunderstanding the site (as I did at first.)  As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following two posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)